# How to skip the unmodified modules importing in PYTHON

Tags: python

I have a lot of modules to import before running each script. But the modules i am importing is same in all the scripts. In case of debugging i have to change some code in one or more modules and again run the script. So each time python imports all the modules from the starting. Is there anyway that i skip importing of modules that haven't modified?

Answer (score 1):

You can reload particular modules with [`reload`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) function, like this

```
reload(math)
```